# How to link CSS to HTML in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

This is my html file:

```html
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Abhya Tripathi|Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav>
<ul id='navbar'>
  <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="welcome-section" class="intro">

<h1>Hey i'am Mimic.</h1>
<p>a web developer</p>


</div>
<div id="projects" class="work">
<h2 class="work-header">These are some of my projects..</h2>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/NNvBQW" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642794/d084d718-6171-11e6-83fa-ede5d0a67ad2.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">Tribute Page</div>
</a>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/ONjoLe" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642771/7cd6a0c4-6171-11e6-87fb-915f6084d104.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">Random Quote Machine</div>
</a>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/PNKdjo" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642772/7d02406c-6171-11e6-8c79-40a2933163dc.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">JavaScript Calculator</div>
</a>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/mVEJag" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642773/7d08cb94-6171-11e6-8c45-22e7cf64683e.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">Map Data Across the Globe</div>
</a>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/wGqEga" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642774/7d091806-6171-11e6-8d47-ecf2f2833fe2.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">Wikipedia Viewer</div>
</a>
<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/KzXQgy" target="_blank" class="project project-tile">
  <img class="project-pic" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15967809/17642775/7d354304-6171-11e6-8b56-66eee4681d88.png" alt="project">
  <div class="project-title">Tic Tac Toe Game</div>
</a>

<a href="https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/" class="show-all" target="_blank">Show all</a>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="contact">
<div class="header">
  <h1>Let's work together...</h1>
  <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
</div>
<a href="https://facebook.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="contact-details">Facebook</a>
<a id='profile-link' href="https://github.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="contact-details">GitHub</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="contact-details">Twitter</a>
<a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="contact-details">Send a mail</a>
<a href="tel:555-555-5555" class="contact-details">Call me</a>
</div>
<footer>**This is just a fake portfolio.. All the projects and contact details given are not real..
<p>&copy; Created for <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/" target="_blank">FreeCodeCamp</a></p>
</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my css file:

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro {
  top: 0;
  background: #e0ebe8;
  min-height: 55vh;
  padding-top: 45vh;
  /*   line-height: 100vh; */
  /*   width:100%;
  height:96vh;
border:solid; */
}

.intro p {
  color: green;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e0ebe8;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #008080;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: green;
}

.work {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.work .work-header {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #008080;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.project {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008080;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  height: 220px;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 40px 100px;
  /*   background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dck40m3wf/image/upload/v1455459914/Portfolio/fancy-floral-pattern-384.jpg") repeat; */
}

.project-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
}

.project-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show-all {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px auto 90px;
   background: #e0ebe8;
  color: #008080;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #90C695;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top:10px;
}


.show-all:hover {
  background: #E4F1FE;
  color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  nav ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul li {
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .project {
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
}

.contact {
  /*   height:800px; */
  /*   min-height:800px; */
  background: #C8F7C5;
  padding-bottom: 160px;
}

.header {
  padding: 160px 0 110px;
}

.contact-details {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 35px 45px 35px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid #90C695;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #e0ebe8;
  color: #008080;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contact-details:hover {
  background: #E4F1FE;
  color: green;
}

footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #22313F;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
}

footer a {
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 367px) {
  /*    #contact{
    min-height:1100px;
  } */
  .contact-details {
    border: 2px solid #90C695;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
  }
}
```

This is my folder structure:
[image]

This is my setting.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'hzfd@hm@%=n8kgsb$@bw^$i%jl(=sn5d$3ifwx4)uy#jrwu9!9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I've put the CSS file under static folder. I tried changing the source in the link to '../blog.css'.
I'm confident that the problem doesn't lie in the settings file because I tried some of my old project's html and CSS content and it works then.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: can you add your settings.py?

Comment: @Taylor Sure,done.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes.Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your file structure should be blog/static/blog/css/blog.css. You tag would look like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/css/style.css' %}">
```

Since i can't explain it any better here is an excerpt from the django website on how static files are found:

"Just like templates, we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in polls/static (rather than creating another polls subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself. "

Answer (score 2):

Essentially this is likely to be due to if you're using production `settings.py` in local development, or local development `settings.py` in production.

Local development:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/static/'),
]
```

Production:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/static/')
```

If this is not the cause of your issues - add you `.css` files possibly might not be linked in your `base.html` file.

You can do so with something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/styles.min.css" %}"/>
```

Hopefully this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `{% load staticfiles %}` instead `{% load static %}` I have had issues like yours before linking my static URL to HTML using `{% load static %}`.
but once I did the static files everything ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Erased the  !DOCTYPE HTML default by sublime text 3 and issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. And tried all the ways mentioned here but none worked. In my case the solution was adding the exact lines in Settings.py file

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always add type="text/css" in your css link since django first checks for the file type before it runs.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/styles.min.css" %}"/>
```